# Getting an ambiguous "The called function should be payable" error

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix

I'm trying to deploy a simple test contract in Remix. However, the compiler does not like this method:

```
function _approveWeth(uint256 _amount) internal {
        IERC20(WETH).approve(ZRX_STAKING_PROXY, _amount);
    }
```

And throws a:

`creation of ctr errored: VM error: revert. revert The transaction has been reverted to the initial state. Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance. Debug the transaction to get more information.`

Whenever I try to deploy this contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

interface IERC20 {

    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);
    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);

    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);


    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
}

contract ctr {
    // Addresses
    address payable OWNER;
    
    address ZRX_STAKING_PROXY = 0xa26e80e7Dea86279c6d778D702Cc413E6CFfA777; // Fee collector
    
    address  WETH = 0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2;
    address  SAI = 0x89d24A6b4CcB1B6fAA2625fE562bDD9a23260359;
    address  DAI = 0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F;

   constructor() public payable {
        _getWeth(msg.value);
        _approveWeth(msg.value);
        OWNER = msg.sender;
    }
     function _getWeth(uint256 _amount) internal {
        (bool success, ) = WETH.call.value(_amount)("");
        require(success, "failed to get weth");
    }

    function _approveWeth(uint256 _amount) internal {
        IERC20(WETH).approve(ZRX_STAKING_PROXY, _amount);
    }
    
}
```

I've tried even changing `_approveWeth` to be `public payable` thinking that was the reason, but  I still get the error until I completely comment out my invocation of the method (then I can deploy). Compiled with 0.5.17.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using the `WETH` mainnet address in a smart contract that you are trying to deploy, I understand, on the Remix javaScript VM environment, a private local blockchain used for testing. Since the address `0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2` is not a smart contract on the test network, the call to `approve` fails in the `_approveWeth` function.

What you can do to successfully deploy and test your `ctr` smart contract:

1. Deploy the `WETH` smart contract on the test network

The code can be found here : https://etherscan.io/address/0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2#code.

2. Get the `WETH` address

You should see on Remix, in the "Deployed Contracts" section,
an icon to the right of the contract address to copy it.

3. In the `ctr` contract, replace `0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2` with the address you obtained.
4. Deploy `ctr` : it should work.

Then you can do the same for `SAI`, `DAI` and `ZRX_STAKING_PROXY` smart contracts.